# What does the Underscore Signify in Code?

Tags: c#

I am reviewing the following code and cannot make sense of it. I know the syntax elements like the use of underscore to discard results, the new keyword, and using keywords. Is the first line of
amethod() superfluous?
Is this somehow equivalent to
MyClass myclass = new MyClass()

```
using aclasslibrary;

private async amethod()
{
_ = new MyClass();
MyClass myclass;

myclass = await classService.Getsomething();

if (myclass != null) 
{ 
  persist (myclass);
}

}
```

MyClass is defined as follows

```
namespace aclasslibrary
{
  public class MyClass
  {
    public int id;
    public SomeClass something;
  }
}
```

Comment: _I know the syntax elements like the underscore operator_ Um, operator?

Comment: the only possible use is if the constructor of that class has a side effect that requires it to be called before other instances can be made. If so thats a terrible design

Comment: MyClass does not have an explicit constructor. It is more like a structure or Data Type Object, with no methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_` acknowledges that the left side of an equation is to be safely ignored. So its saying ignore the result of the `new MyClass();`.

It appears to be a rookie mistake from a new learner because the following line declares a reference holder, which is not initialized; and could actually use such an initialization.

Comment: So it does appear to be bad if not wrong code? After discarding the instance created in the first line, does the second line benefit from it in any way. I found this line in running code, so I have to be very careful. and by the way thanks

Comment: The only reason to do something like that, new up an object to not reference, would be if the constructor does some specific behavior, such as logging onto a database or some sort. But that would be rare.